# voiceover in ios and talkback in android not able to access the input element

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover, talkback

voiceover in ios and talkback in android not able to access the input element while double clicking the button. on using tabindex="0" for input element it become accessible but still not accessible with double click.Also is there a way to test voiceover or talkback on desktop.

```
  type="button"
  id="Pivot12-Tab1"
  class="ms-Button ms-Button--action ms-Button--command ms-Pivot-link link-221"
  role="tab"
  aria-selected="false"
  name="Search"
  data-content="Search"
  data-is-focusable="true"
  tabindex="0"
>
  <span
    class="ms-Button-flexContainer flexContainer-217"
    data-automationid="splitbuttonprimary"
  >
    <div class="ms-SearchBox root-222">
      <div
        class="ms-SearchBox-iconContainer iconContainer-223"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <i
          data-icon-name="Search"
          aria-hidden="true"
          class="ms-SearchBox-icon icon-228"
          ></i
        >
      </div>
      <input
        id="SearchBox20"
        class="ms-SearchBox-field field-226"
        placeholder="Search by job title or ID"
        role="searchbox"
        aria-label="Search by job title or ID"
        value=""
        tabindex="-1"
      />
    </div>
  </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Is there some JS to go with this example? From what I can see I guess you are trying to make a search container appear after pressing the "search" button. The problems seem to be two fold and I can't tell if your JS fixes them, first you have an `aria-hidden` div surrounding the search box, which removes it from the accessibility tree. Secondly `tabindex="-1"` makes the input not able to receive focus. Not sure why you want it to work on double click either? Could you turn it into an actual fiddle so we can help please?

Comment: I have asked for fiddles on your other questions but you don't seem to answer. Fiddles are an essential tool for us to see the whole picture, I know they take a little while to set up but without them a lot of the questions you ask are hard for us to test and see where the issue is.